# Illegal Thread State Exception when starting a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, state

Im trying to create 4 threads and give them tasks to do. However I keep getting IllegalThreadStateException. I lurked questions here but none seem to help me.
Heres the crucial code fragment:

```
Sorter worker1 = new Sorter(theView,1);
Sorter worker2 = new Sorter(theView,2);
Sorter worker3 = new Sorter(theView,3);
Sorter worker4 = new Sorter(theView,4);

for(int nextTask=0 ; nextTask<List_of_FileContentsLists.size() ; nextTask++){
    if(worker1.busy == false){
        worker1.acquireTask(List_of_FileContentsLists.get(nextTask),fileList[nextTask]);
        worker1.start();
    }
    else if(worker2.busy == false){
        worker2.acquireTask(List_of_FileContentsLists.get(nextTask),fileList[nextTask]);
        worker2.start();
    }
    else if(worker3.busy == false){
        worker3.acquireTask(List_of_FileContentsLists.get(nextTask),fileList[nextTask]);
        worker3.start();
    }
    else if(worker4.busy == false){
        worker4.acquireTask(List_of_FileContentsLists.get(nextTask),fileList[nextTask]);
        worker4.start();
    }
    else{
        nextTask--;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Is it legal to call the start method twice on the same Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215548/is-it-legal-to-call-the-start-method-twice-on-the-same-thread)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215548/is-it-legal-to-call-the-start-method-twice-on-the-same-thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every worker that you start once, you cannot start it repeatedly as you have done through your looping. I am hoping that the WorkerN stands for different threads.

IllegalThreadState arises when you try to change thread's state to the state not allowed. For more reference, go through the javadoc:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalThreadStateException.html

Answer (score 1):

If `List_of_FileContentsLists.size()` > 1, you will get `IllegalThreadStateException`

For example sake, assume that `List_of_FileContentsLists.size()` = 2 and `worker1.busy = false`.

When `nextTask` is 0, you have started the thread since 0 < 2.

In second iteration, nextTask is 1 and still 1 < 2.

As per your logic, you try to `start()` a thread, which has been already started.

[start()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start--)

> Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls the run method of this thread.
>
> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.

Suggestions:

1. Don't call `start()` method more than once. Change your `for` loop accordingly.
2. Start an `ExecutorService` and post `Runnable` or `Callable` task to `ExecutorService`.