# How to reset a thread when it finishes

Tags: python, multithreading, kivy

I am using kivy and I'm trying to find a way to "reset" my thread after its finished, though I know that resetting threads is impossible. So, how would I have a thread run after its run once before if I tell it to? I have a screen set up with a button that when pressed runs a thread for 5 seconds then after 5 seconds returns me to the original screen, But if I press the button after its been pressed before I get an error saying threads can only be used once. Here is the code for the thread. I'm calling it when the screen first appears using  `on_pre_enter()`

```
def countdown1():
    seconds = 5
    for i in range(seconds):
        timeleft = seconds-i
        print(str(timeleft) + " seconds remain")
        time.sleep(1)
    print("out of time")
    sm.current = "Evaluation"
    seconds = 5

countdown1_thread = threading.Thread(target = countdown1)
```

Comment: What is the command that your `Button` runs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it legal to call the start method twice on the same Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215548/is-it-legal-to-call-the-start-method-twice-on-the-same-thread)

Comment: `Button:
            
            pos_hint:{"x":0.5, "y": 0.6}
            size_hint:0.3,0.1
            text: "press me"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "Questions"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"`

Comment: It's in my Kv file and takes me to the screen where the thread is run. But if I press it after the thread is run I get th error

Comment: I don't see the code that actually starts the thread?

Comment: Are you doing `countdown1_thread.start()` somewhere?

Comment: `def on_pre_enter(self):
        print("callback")
        countdown1_thread.start()`

Comment: The thread is started using `on_pre_enter()` not with the button. The button just loads the page where the thread is started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
countdown1_thread.start()
```

with:

```
threading.Thread(target = countdown1).start()
```